# Simple SQL Search within a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that will look like this:

```
05124110 LMY RET 2015
```

I need in SQL to return a row if there is `LMY` and `RET` it can be as one piece
`LMY RET` but maybe better to check for  both separately in case the users add one extra blank.

Comment: have you tried `LIKE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from [table] where [column] like '%LMY%' and [column] like '%RET%'
```

Note that this will be case-insensitive, so 'lmy ret' will be returned as well. This will also return things that have "RET LMY"; I'm not sure if that's desired or not.

Comment: the thing is the string is in one column.

Comment: @user1086533 That is what my answer was assuming.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourColumn LIKE '%LMY%RET%'
```